# SQL join sum groupby where

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, group-by

I have following two tables:
[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fac8ebce7464a6846bb4d396856fa2c8)

As a result I need a list of 'name' from tab1, where the sum of 'dur' is 10 or bigger. The connection between the two table is the 'number' from tab1 which can be found in column 'xxx' or 'yyy' from tab2.
So the expected output should be: Jack, Anna

Because the sum of 'dur' for Jack(1234) is 10 and the sum of 'dur' for Anna(7582) is 12.

So far I know how to get the sum based on one column XXX:

```
SELECT tab1.name FROM tab1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT xxx, SUM(dur) AS total_dur
  FROM tab2
  GROUP BY xxx)
tab2 ON tab1.number=tab2.xxx
WHERE total_dur >=10
```

but how do I also consider the second 'yyy' column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `OR` in the join condition to check two columns. Using `HAVING` might also make the query a bit more readable.

```
SELECT name FROM tab1
JOIN tab2 ON xxx = number OR yyy = number
GROUP BY name
HAVING SUM(dur) >= 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can unpivot the data.  In Postgres, I would suggest a lateral join:

```
SELECT tab1.name
FROM tab1 INNER JOIN
     (SELECT v.col, SUM(dur) AS total_dur
      FROM tab2 CROSS JOIN LATERAL
           (VALUES (tab2.xxx), (tab2.yyy)) v(col)
      GROUP BY v.col
     ) tab2
     ON tab1.number = tab2.col
WHERE total_dur >= 10;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=20d1f3f166890d5797a5a8395a554939) is a db<>fiddle.